# Qt - Download Images from web

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write an application using Qt/C++ to download images from web. The program will be provided a list of URLs as a text file, and should open each URL and download all images in each website.

In order to do so, I subclass QNetworkAccessManager and override `createRequest` method/function like below:

```
QNetworkReply* clsNAM::createRequest(Operation op,const QNetworkRequest & req,
                                                    QIODevice * outgoingData )
{
    return new clsNR(QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(_op,_req,_outgoingData));
}
```

My subclass of QNetworkReply class, clsNR, identifies the type of the reply from its raw header, something like:

```
bool clsNR::isImage()
{
    if(this->rawHeader("Content-Type").toLower().startsWith("image"))
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

As I get readyRead signal (which means there is data available to read) ,I store the coming in a QbyteArray. I have connected a slot in clsNR to save the image when the QNetworkReply is finished. It looks like:

```
void clsNR::slotCloseConnection()
{
    if(isImage())
    {
      QImage image;
      bool bool1 = image.loadFromData(ContentData);
      QString name(QDir::homePath());
      name.append(this->url().path());
      bool bool2 = image.save(name,0,-1);
    }
}
```

There is something wrong with my saving. `bool1` is `true`, but `bool2` is `false`. The reason I'm using the url path for the name is to generate unique name for images. When I print out the name, it's something like:

```
"/home/guest/images/splash/3.jpg"
```

So My questions would be:

1. What I'm doing wrong with QImage?
2. Can I use QFile and QStream to write down the images instead?

Comment: Does that directory already exist?

Comment: well...no, I just create the folder, and it seems to work perfectly...I'm an idiot... thanks though! Btw you can write it as an answer, anb I can accept it.

Comment: BTW, no, you don't need to use QImage.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add something else, like Mat said in your comment. If you need to check if the directory exists use [Qdir::exists()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#exists-2) and if you need to create it use [QDir::mkdir()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#mkdir)